# Interaction based recommendation system dataset

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

Is there a recommendation system dataset where the data is not in term of ratings, but number of times a user has interacted with the item? I know last.fm has a set, but it is rather small and I have not found other published results on it. Hopefully the set also has existing benchmarks.

Comment: Should you ask on opendata?

Comment: What **data** would make this a *recommendation system* dataset? If you only have items + number of interactions there are no recommendations in the data itself. Please [edit] your question to either include that or remove any mention of *recommendation*. Also [read this](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) please